# Pagination a loop of table outputs

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables that i join in an sql query. then i pull that sql query once for every table and limit it to the top 10 results

i have tried to paginate the query basically by limiting the amount of data pulled but it wrecks my table output.

here is the current code

```
<?php
                $a = 1;
                $b = 1;

                for( $i = 0; $i < 300; $i++){
                    $sql = "SELECT player.ID, player.Login, localrecord.map_id , localrecord.score FROM player JOIN localrecord ON player.ID = localrecord.Player_Id WHERE map_id = $a Order By score ASC   LIMIT 10";

                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    $sql2 = "SELECT file FROM map WHERE ID = $a";
                    $mapName = $conn->query($sql2);
                    $mapNamerow = $mapName->fetch_assoc();

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row

                        $WRQuery = "SELECT time_author FROM map WHERE ID =$a";
                        $WRResults = $conn->query($WRQuery);
                        $WRrow = $WRResults->fetch_assoc();

                        $WRtime = $WRrow['time_author'];
                        $WRmilliseconds = $WRtime % 1000;
                        $WRtime = floor($WRtime / 1000);
                        $WRseconds = $WRtime  % 60;
                        $WRtime = floor($WRtime / 60);
                        $WRminutes = $WRtime  % 60;
                        $WRtime = floor($WRtime / 60);


                        echo  "<p class='mapTitle'> " . substr($mapNamerow['file'],11);
                        echo "<br/>Author's Time: " . $WRminutes . ":". $WRseconds.".". $WRmilliseconds . "</p>";
                        echo "<table border='1'>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Score <br/> Min:Sec.Mil</th>
                                </tr>";



                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


                        $time = $row['score'];
                        $milliseconds = $time % 1000;
                        $time = floor($time / 1000);
                        $seconds = $time  % 60;
                        $time = floor($time / 60);
                        $minutes = $time  % 60;
                        $time = floor($time / 60);
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['Login'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $minutes.':'.$seconds.'.'.$milliseconds . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "<br/>";

                    }
                    $a++;
                }
            ?>
```

```
millisecond-tm-121.Gbx
Author's Time: 0:14.344

Name    Score Min:Sec.Mil

mattman0123 0:18.309

millisecond-tm-107.Gbx
Author's Time: 0:16.966

Name    Score  Min:Sec.Mil

mattman0123 0:17.202
```

this is the current out put;

I have roughly 200 tables i want to display but i dont want them to show all the tables at once.

Any ideas?